# How efficient is the .find() function in JavaScript? Is it faster than .map() or .forEach()?

Tags: javascript

Is using `.find()` in JavaScript inefficient as compared to using `.map()` or `.forEach()` ?

For example, in case of an array of objects :

`var arr=[{name:"vishek",ID:222,subjects:["science","maths","politics"]}]`

For such an array, is it efficient to use `.find` to find a particular object or `.map()`?

Comment: Well, `find` returns the first match, so in that sense you likely end up iterating through fewer elements of the array than the other methods.

Comment: If you have a large amount of data and you need to perform lookups, the real answer is to choose a better data structure than a simple array.

Comment: Neither `.map()` nor `.forEach()` are meant to only "find" an element.

Comment: Each Array method has a use case. If you want to `find` one element in your array, then you use find. If you want to find `some` elements, then you use some, if you want to change the elements based with something else, you use `map`, etc.

Comment: The easiest way to find the answer would have been to time the functions and find out your self. Like this for example: https://jsfiddle.net/gp018qrs/